# Allow UIImagePickerController to edit video but not images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Uploading an image or video in **Whatsapp**, seems to use a `UIImagePicker`.

It's possible to edit video in that view, but images can't be edited. It seems that in the SDK, the `allowsEditing` property determines whether editing is allowed for both images and video.

How can I get the behavior like Whatsapp, where video can be edited but images cannot?

Comment: have you tried passing a different attribute after the selection in the image picker? as in, depending on what they selected.

Comment: hi im trying to achieve the same thing. atm it seems you have been able to get the edit screen - the reduce clip to a certain length (whatsapp 45 seconds) - how can i achieve just that as i have just gotten to the stage of being able to display the imagepicker.. i can edit images scale and move but i am not able to edit videos when selecting large video files.. it just starts compressing straight away... i need the screen just before then... the ability to trim the video... any help?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this functionality by listening for notifications from the picker. Sign-up in ViewDidLoad

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(imageCaptured:)
                                             name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil];
```

Than determine when to allowing editing

```
   - (void) imageCaptured:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
       if (self.pickerController.cameraCaptureMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo) {
            self.pickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
         }
         else{
            self.pickerController.allowsEditing = NO; 
         {
   }
```

Comment: This seemed like it should work, however I can't get it to work on iOS 7 :(

Comment: Looks hacky and therefore unreliable. I would recommend using a custom image / video picker.

Answer (score 1):

To disallow image editing set `allowsEditing = false`.

To allow video editing, present the picked video in a `UIVideoEditorController`.

Or use a custom image / video picker that you can configure to your liking.