# How to disable the edit option in UIImagePickerController when it is a gallery image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery

I just want to be able to edit when it's a video. I have managed to do this when the selection is from the camera. but I don't know how to do it from the gallery.

```
let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraController.sourceType = .camera
        cameraController.allowsEditing = cameraController.cameraCaptureMode == .video
```

Answer (score 1):

when you set `cameraController.sourceType = .photoLibrary`  then you can pass `.allowEditing = false`.

Comment: Yes, bu if I select a video is not edited either (and in this case I want to)

Comment: Bro, you need to have two option such as pick from photoLib and using Camera. Otherwise you can't provide both with different function.

Comment: Yes, but sourceType = .photoLibrary return videos and photos because mediaTypes are kUTTypeMovie and kUTTypeImage

Comment: ok so for this as far as I know you have to follow this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/18728142/9532353

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()

if cameraController.sourceType == .camera {
     cameraController.allowsEditing = true
} else if cameraController.sourceType == .photoLibrary {
     cameraController.allowsEditing = false
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. If I use it in false, I don't have the option to edit in the video selection either.

Comment: ok, then you have to do some conditional code for it. for Ex. if you are choose `cameraController.sourceType = .photoLibrary` then `cameraController.allowEditing = false` othewise  `cameraController.allowEditing = true`

Comment: Yes, but sourceType = .photoLibrary return videos and photos because mediaTypes are kUTTypeMovie and  kUTTypeImage

Answer (score 0):

```
let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()

if cameraController.sourceType == .camera{
     cameraController.allowsEditing = cameraController.cameraCaptureMode == .video
}else if cameraController.sourceType == .photoLibrary{
     cameraController.allowsEditing = false
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me, .photoLibrary return videos and photos because mediaTypes are kUTTypeMovie and kUTTypeImage